# Elastic search: why does wildcard query return no result?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ES. I created an index:

```
PUT test
    {
        "mappings": {
            "logEvent":{
                "dynamic": "false",
                "properties": {
                        "hostName":{
                            "type": "keyword"

                        },
                        "message":{
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                        "timeStamp":{
                            type:"date"
                        }
                    }
             }
        }
    }
```

I inserted a row

```
"User:x;level:x1; loged in
```

Then I tryied to run the query:

```
GET test/logEvent/_search
{
    "query":{
       "wildcard":{
         "message": "User:*;level:x1; loged in"
       }
    }
}
```

I get nothing in return from query. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Fixed spelling and code formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard query can be used only on **not analyzed** fields. You need to change your mapping so that message is multi-field, both text and keyword:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "logEvent": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "hostName": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timeStamp": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then query with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "message.keyword": "User:*;level:x1; loged in"
    }
  }
}
```

In the mappings, set `ignore_above` to the max length of your message